# Batch accessing Google or Bing Maps from C#

Tags: c#, gps, maps

Good morning,

I am currently working on a project in which I need to compute the pairwise distance between some 4000 points. Since I have the coordinates of all the points, computing the straight-line distance between them was not very difficult... But now I would like to compute the same ~ 8 million distances using not the straight-line path but the shortest path by road, as given by GPS software. Can I access Google/Bing/other map services from C# to compute these distances?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I access Google/Bing/other map services from C# to compute these distances?

Probably not.

Google's [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits) on usage limits:

> Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day. Individual directions requests may contain up to 8 intermediate waypoints in the request. Google Maps Premier customers may query up to 100,000 directions requests per day, with up to 23 waypoints allowed in each request.

Bing also [has limits](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing.aspx):

> 1. Use is on public-facing, non-password protected Web sites
> 2. Limit of 125,000 sessions or 500,000 transactions in a 12 month period

Answer (score 0):

For this task,Google has Directions Web Services that can generate route information through json and xml formats.

In order to access this web services,you need to receive a private key from Google.
And you need to specify the information as request string,described in [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

Then you should convert your key to **base64string** within **HMACSHA1** algorithm.There is a documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/#CSharpSignatureExample).

In the end you have a url with your request information plus your key.Then,you can simply request this url to get xml and json.All you have to do is to read response.

Hope this helps

Myra